# List<Map<String,dynamic> or database which is best to ship flutter app with prepopulated data

Tags: flutter

I am developing a flutter app which mainly contains contact details of govt offices
The office class is like

```
class Office {
  final String title;
  final String? subTitle;
  final String? id;
  final String? address;
  final List<double>? location;
  final String? mailId;
  final List<String>? phNo;

  Office({
    required this.title,
    this.subTitle,
    this.id,
    this.address,
    this.location,
    this.mailId,
    this.phNo});
}
```

and the data may like

```
final Map<String, dynamic> regOfficesList = { 'Head Office': [
    Office(
      title: 'Inspector General of Revenue',
      subTitle: 'HEAD OFFICE',
      address:
          'Near District Court, Vanchiyoor',
      phNo: ['043572456',],
      mailId: 'regig@gamil.com',
      location: [9.49170690098212, 26.94105228901716],
     
    )
  ],'Zonal offices:.....}
```

There are 20k to 30k contacts details are their

should I store the  the data like this or use any database . Please advice

Comment: Hey mate, answer to this depends on what trade offs you want to make and is not straightforward. You can certainly ship it hardcoded if that's your jam. All that code will get loaded into memory, and could slow down your app's startup and increase mem usage. (though 30k records is probably peanuts for a decent phone today). Storing in a DB allows you to update it in other ways without updating your app and reduce mem usage, spped up app load .etc. Depending on these and likely other reasons, you can pick the right approach. Stackoverflow prefers not to provide answers based on opinion.